# Include directive before html render

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I tried wrapping my head around the following problem:

1. I have a html string which I render using `ng-bind-html`
2. I managed to change a given placeholder (in the html string) with a directive (or more). For example I have: `[placeholder]test[/placeholder]` and replaced with `<my-directive></my-directive>` for a certain functionality.

This approach is needed to make some content dynamic.

When rendering the html string I notice that the directive is missing, I understand, but is there a way to render it and make the directive functionally?

P.S:

- Tried rendering it as a normal string but the html is escaped
- Tried using `$sce.trustAsHtml()`
- I cannot apply `$compile(element.contents())(scope);` since the directive is not triggered

Comment: Just make directive that will take string as parameter replace some text, compile result and add it to DOM.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, this is the first time I have ever done such implementation

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to do achieve this by doing the following:

1. Add the directive in the html:

   `<my-directive update-data-trigger="someObject.content" data="someObject"></<my-directive>`
2. The directive:

`app.directive("myDirective", function ($compile) {
  return {
    replace:true,
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
      //Data holds the html in the content attribute
      data: '=',
      updateDataTrigger: '='
    },
    link: function ($scope, element) {
      //Add a watcher to refresh data because the loaded data passed is async
      $scope.$watch('updateDataTrigger', function(){
        //Check if data passed has been loaded with our desired object
        if($scope.updateDataTrigger != null) {
          //Do some content manipulation here
          //Append directives to the content as well
          //render as html
          element.html(data.content);
          $compile(element.contents())($scope);
        }
      });
    }
  }
});`

Comment: 'data' can be quite big right? 100-200-1000 symbols - watching such strings looks weird and should be slow, so may be better is adding special variable to watch: <my-directive data="someObject" update-data-trigger="updateTrigger"></<my-directive>.